# Customize The Native Alert dialog in flutter applicaton for iOS or Android for Face Id implementation

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-alertdialog

Below is the method to authenticate biometric access in flutter application which is successfully implemented.
If the error happens it shows a alert dialog box as shown in the image in iOS application, I want to customize this alert dialog box, how can I do that?

AlertBox Image [image]

this alert dialog is only shown when `useErrorDialogs` is set to `true` as in the below code.

this is referred from [Face Id Lock Implementation in Flutter](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-local-authentication-using-biometrics/)

```
Future<void> _authenticateUser() async {
    bool isAuthenticated = false;
    try {
      isAuthenticated = await _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason:
            "Please authenticate to view your transaction overview",
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: true,
      );
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    isAuthenticated
        ? print('User is authenticated!')
        : print('User is not authenticated.');

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TransactionScreen(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it. For security reasons, the whole biometric authentication process is handled by iOS outside your app.