# FLUTTER - How to customise native popup in iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, native

I am implementing a screen where the user can only authenticate using biometric or application pincode, using the local_auth package in flutter. I have set `useBiometricOnly:true` despite that iOS pop-up shows "enter password" in the native popup. When i click on that options, then nothing happens. I dont want to display "enter password" on the screen because i dont want the user to enter the system password.

Is there a way to customise the native iOS popup in flutter?

[image: "enter password" should not be there]

Comment: What kind of iOS device have you been using? Is it a Physical device or a simulated device? I'm asking because both types have their behaviour. So, the output of the same code may differ or vary on different devices.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are seeing?  There should never be a prompt for a *password*, only a *passcode*.  There is no option to use biometrics only on iOS. If you specify `useBiometricsOnly` to this plugin, it requests `deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` which requests biometric authentication and if that fails 3 times then it offers a fallback to passcode.  If you specify `false` for `useBiometricsOnly` then you will see the fallback option immediately along with the biometric prompt

Comment: You will get a `true` response to your authentication regardless of whether the user used the passcode or biometric authentication with no indication as to which was used.

Comment: @DharamBudh i used it on both simulator as well as physical device (iPhone 12)

Comment: @SrastiVerma, A few months ago, I was playing with this "local_auth" package & I also created a Git Repository. In there, I demonstrated all the possible usage & outcomes of this package. And your mentioned functionality is working as expected in my sample project. Here's the video: https://www.veed.io/view/3114d4da-73e1-4a83-8de4-55d142d24383?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

Comment: @DharamBudh you need to max out your attempts so that the popup gives you the prompt to "enter password". Can you check this on your device/emulator?

Comment: I attempted ten times & your mentioned issue isn't happening in my iOS simulator. I don't have any physical device & the iOS simulator doesn't support passcode/password. So, in the iOS simulator, there are no options for fallback. I can try indefinitely without a fallback. If you want to try & test out my code, feel free to ask. Perhaps it may work with a physical device.

Comment: @DharamBudhI tested on simulators as well as a physical device, so far i am still getting "enter password" on iOS. It works fine on android. I am attaching a screenshot of the popup in my post.

Comment: no, you can't since it's handled by the system :)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057479/customize-the-native-alert-dialog-in-flutter-applicaton-for-ios-or-android-for-f